# Client Keystore, TrustStore, LDAP Credential

Tags: ldap, keystore, truststore, cacerts

I am having an issue with keystore, truststore, and LDAP credentials for Google.

I am using GraalVM 22.2 on JDK17 for the test.

I created a test class to be able to log into Google LDAP.  Once, I figure out how to do it in the test, then I can move it into our application.

I downloaded my Google LDAP credential and key.  I then followed the instructions from Google to create a KeyStore:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/9089736?hl=en#other-java-applications

According to Google's instructions, you just add the following to your System properties:

> -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=[File Path to KeyStore] -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=[KeyStore Pass]
>
> -- OR --
>
> System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "[File Path to KeyStore]");
> System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "[KeyStore Pass]");

The problem with this is we will have a KeyStore with a password that corresponds with a specific LDAP server.  This is due to the fact that our application will be able to connect to multiple LDAP servers.

After doing some research, I saw you can create an SSLSocketFactory and set the property "***java.naming.ldap.factory.socket***".  From there, you can add the KeyStore to use via the TrustManager, or KeyManager.

My problem is, when trying to connect to the Google LDAP server; the SSLSocketFactory is completely ignored. How do I know? None of the debugging statements in the SSLSocketFactory, TrustManger, or KeyManager are printed out. (I added a KeyStoreManager for debugging purposes.)

I even tried to import the keystore into cacerts with no luck.  In fact, I had multiple problems importing because "keytool" kept complaining about the JKS vs PKCS12 format.

The only way I can connect successfully is to add the 2 System properties. I know I am missing something simple that will explain why it is not working correctly.  Anyone got any ideas?

Here is my test class:

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;


public class LDAPIT {

    public static final String JAVA_NAMING_LDAP_FACTORY_SOCKET = "java.naming.ldap.factory.socket";

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final LDAPIT test = new LDAPIT();

        try {
            test.run();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    public void run() throws Exception {

        final Console cnsl = System.console();

        if (cnsl == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Console is null");
        }

        final String url = cnsl.readLine("Enter URL: ");
        final String user = cnsl.readLine("Enter username : ");
        final String password = String.valueOf(cnsl.readPassword("Enter password : "));

        System.out.println("Start Trying to Connect to LDAP: " + url);
        System.out.println("With User: " + user);

        System.out.println("Creating LDAP Properties");

        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user);
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
        props.put(JAVA_NAMING_LDAP_FACTORY_SOCKET, MySSLSocketFactory.class.getName());

        System.out.println("LDAP Properties without password: " + props);

        props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

//        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "[File Path to KeyStore]");
//        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "[KeyStore Pass]");

        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to LDAP Server");

            final InitialDirContext idc = new InitialDirContext(props);

            System.out.println("Successfully connected to LDAP");

            idc.close();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("End Trying to Connect to LDAP");
    }

    public static class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

        private SSLSocketFactory socketFactory;

        public MySSLSocketFactory() {

            try {
                System.out.println("Creating Key Manager");

                final MyKeyManager keyManager = new MyKeyManager();
                final KeyManager[] keyManagers = {keyManager};

                System.out.println("Creating Trust Manager");

                final MyTrustManager trustManager = new MyTrustManager();
                final TrustManager[] trustManagers = {trustManager};

                System.out.println("Creating Socket Context");

                final SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

                System.out.println("Initializing Socket Context");

                ctx.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());

                System.out.println("Creating Socket Factory");

                socketFactory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
            } catch (final Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {

            return socketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {

            return socketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String string, int i, boolean bln) throws IOException {

            System.out.println("Creating Socket with: Socket, String, int, Boolean");

            return socketFactory.createSocket(socket, string, i, bln);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(final Socket s, final InputStream consumed, final boolean autoClose) throws IOException {

            System.out.println("Creating Socket with: Socket, InputStream, Boolean");

            return super.createSocket(s, consumed, autoClose);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {

            System.out.println("Creating Socket without parameters");

            return super.createSocket();
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(String string, int i) throws IOException {

            System.out.println("Creating Socket with: String ,int");

            return socketFactory.createSocket(string, i);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(String string, int i, InetAddress ia, int i1) throws IOException {

            System.out.println("Creating Socket with: String, int, InetAddress, int");

            return socketFactory.createSocket(string, i, ia, i1);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(InetAddress ia, int i) throws IOException {

            System.out.println("Creating Socket with: InetAddress, int");

            return socketFactory.createSocket(ia, i);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(InetAddress ia, int i, InetAddress ia1, int i1) throws IOException {

            System.out.println("Creating Socket with: InetAddress, InetAddress, int");

            return socketFactory.createSocket(ia, i, ia1, i1);
        }

    }

    public static class MyKeyManager implements X509KeyManager {

        @Override
        public String[] getClientAliases(final String keyType, final Principal[] issuers) {

            System.out.println("Getting Client Aliases: String, Principal[]");

            return new String[0];
        }

        @Override
        public String chooseClientAlias(final String[] keyType, final Principal[] issuers, final Socket socket) {

            System.out.println("Choosing Client Alias: String[], Principal[], Socket");

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getServerAliases(final String keyType, final Principal[] issuers) {

            System.out.println("Getting Server Aliases: String, Principal[]");

            return new String[0];
        }

        @Override
        public String chooseServerAlias(final String keyType, final Principal[] issuers, final Socket socket) {

            System.out.println("Choosing Server Aliases: String, Principal[], Socket");

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(final String alias) {

            System.out.println("Getting Certificate Chain: String");

            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }

        @Override
        public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(final String alias) {

            System.out.println("Getting Private Key: String");
            
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static class MyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

        private X509TrustManager gTrustManager;

        public MyTrustManager() {

            System.out.println("Creating My Trust Manager");

            initTrustManager();

            System.out.println("Created My Trust Manager");
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {

            if (gTrustManager != null) {
                gTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {

            if (gTrustManager != null) {
                gTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {

            return gTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
        }


        private void initTrustManager() {

            try {
                final String keystoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();

                System.out.println("Loading Keystore Type: " + keystoreType);

                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keystoreType);

                System.out.println("Loading CA Certs");

                loadCACerts(keyStore);

                System.out.println("Creating SSL Context");

                System.out.println("Creating Trust Manager");

                gTrustManager = getTrustManager(keyStore);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        private void loadCACerts(final KeyStore keyStore) throws Exception {

            final File keyStoreFile = new File("[File Path to KeyStore]]");

            System.out.println("Loading Keystore: " + keyStoreFile.getAbsolutePath());

            try (final FileInputStream keyStoreInputStream = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile)) {
                keyStore.load(keyStoreInputStream, "[KeyStore Pass]".toCharArray());
            }

            System.out.println("Keystore Loaded");
        }

        private X509TrustManager getTrustManager(final KeyStore k) throws Exception {

            final String defaultAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();

            System.out.println("Loading Trust Manager Algorithm: " + defaultAlgorithm);

            final TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(defaultAlgorithm);

            System.out.println("Initializing Trust Manager Factory");

            tmf.init(k);

            System.out.println("Getting Trust Managers");

            final TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();

            int arraySize = 0;

            if (tms != null) {
                arraySize = tms.length;
            }

            System.out.println("Iterating through Trust Managers: " + arraySize);

            for (final TrustManager tm : tms) {

                System.out.println("Trust Manager: " + tm.getClass().getName());

                if (tm instanceof final X509TrustManager x509TrustManager) {
                    System.out.println("Returning X509TrustManager");

                    return x509TrustManager;
                }

            }

            System.out.println("Could not find correct Trust Manager, returning Null");

            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you know it...after I ask the question I figure it out.  The answer was you MUST implement the 'getDefault()' method in your custom SSLSocketFactory.  I knew it was something simple.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ssl.html

Look at **Using Custom Sockets**.